# Unable to read/write to linked server (Ms Access) from Stored Procedure or Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, sql-server-2016

I have a database in SQL Server, when a tuple inserted to a specific table I want the inserted record to be inserted to my Ms access database as well. I have already linked the access database to my Linked Server I can do any type of DML operations on that. When I bound the insert operation of MS access to after insert trigger of that specific table I get below error.

```
The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "COMMON" does not support the required transaction interface.
```

if anybody knows the workaround that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doing this in a trigger seems like a bad idea. If the `INSERT` to the access database fails, so will the `INSERT` on the SQL Server. Smells like a XY problem.

Comment: If you want Access to have the same data as your sql server why not make it an external table in Access? Then you don't need to go through all this effort to keep the tables in synch, you just reference the same table. And you only need one copy of the data instead of two.

Comment: we have an access based database we have made it online but this access database is a common database which is used for other systems as well. So in order to keep our common database updated, we need to populate and shared with other systems which are separate from ours.                                                               I also implemented that by delegating to SQL Agent to execute the insertion process but the problem still exists. I think the problem is somewhere in the permission.